# ImageMagick Command Line convert PNG to EPS with Transparency

Tags: imagemagick, png, transparency, eps

I am trying to do a simple conversion from a transparent PNG file to EPS with transparency and currently my command looks like this:

convert "image1.png" "image1.eps"

It looks like all I am getting is a black image. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Converting a PNG to an EPS is more than just a simple format conversion. Its changing from a raster image to a vector image, so the raster image has to be "[traced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_tracing)". The popular command line tool for doing this is [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/). With `potrace` installed (and its component tool `mkbitmap`) you could do it with something like this:

```
convert image1.png image1.bmp
mkbitmap image1.bmp -o image1.pgm
potrace image1.pgm -e -o image1.eps
```

The call to `mkbitmap` converts the color image to a graymap more suitable for tracing.
This will yield an eps with black lines on a white background. If you need a full color trace, [inkskape](https://inkscape.org/en/) is a GUI tool for doing this, and an inkscape user homebrewed a command line tool to do it, which can be found [here](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?p=44911)